# How to upload binary blob

Tags: javascript, python, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

I am attempting to send some binary data from a client via a blob to a django rest server, but the content of the received file ends up being "{}" independently of the content of the blob. I do not want to upload using base64 encoding.

sample client code:

```
    fetch("myserver/upload/file", {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token mytoken',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="filename.dat"'
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: new Blob(Array.from(Array(10000).keys()))
    );
```

On the server side I have a view class:

```py
    from rest_framework import generics
    from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
    from rest_framework.response import Response

    class MyView(generics.GenericAPIView):
        parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

        def post(self, request):
            f = request.data.get('file')

            # some processing of file...

            return Response(
                {"response_info_key": "response_info_value"},
                status = 201
            )
```

What I observe independently of whether I send the post using jquery, fetch or  xhr, and independently of blob content, what is received on server side is a file object whose only content is the two characters "{" and "}". I am required to add the Content-Disposition header, but not confident that this is the form it should have.

If I on the other hand set a "binary" body using Postman and the same headers, and specify file, the server successfully receives the file. How should I correct my POST request to make it work in a Javascript client?

Python version: 2.7.6

Django==1.11

requests==2.22.0

djangorestframework==3.6.2

**EDIT:**
It seems like request header has 'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH': 2 on the server side, while the CONTENT-LENGTH on client side of the request is ~10^4

Answer (score 1):

I think data from the frontend should be send in `data` not in `body` and the data you are expecting should look something like this:

```
data = {
    "file": new Blob(Array.from(Array(10000).keys()))
}
```

Now you can send the about `data` as

`body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be string or {object}!`

Comment: [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) does not seem to have a `data` field. Do you have any documentation for this?

Comment: Yes fetch doesn't have data, you need to send data in the body itself, Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: If i set `body: {data: {"file": new Blob(Array.from(Array(10000).keys()))}}`, then on the server-side the content changes to the string `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Send data as: `body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!`, Please go through the shared documentation.

Comment: This way, all i get is the string `{"data":{"file":{}}}`, which i interpret as JSON.stringify is not intended for binary data. I have read the documentation, and what you are referring to seems to be how to use `fetch` to post JSON-data?

Comment: How you are sending data looks good but how you are receiving it on the backend looks confusing to me, By that I mean, In `request.data` there has to be a `file` key-value data. Do check what are you getting in `request.data` dictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199579/discussion-between-thisshri-and-m-t).

Answer (score 1):

You can send the binary blob using `FormData` without it being modified.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('content', new Blob(Array.from(Array(10000).keys())));

fetch("myserver/upload/file", {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Token mytoken',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="filename.dat"'
  },
  method: "POST",
  body: formData
);
```

Comment: When I try this, I the content-type changes to 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary8npSGzGOP99U6W2N', but otherwise the result is the same. When combined with changing "FileUploadParser" with "MultiPartParser", then request.data is just an empty querydict. Any ideas?